# Print all in memory object references with count

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to get all object/variable references in current running application with count? I don't have objects/variable names.

I tried:

```
locals()
globals()
gc.get_objects()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `sys.gettotalrefcount()` is available if running the debug build of Python (python_d.exe).  It's useful when writing Python C extensions to verify if a function is leaking references.

Comment: Not running in debug mode

Comment: @codec That’s the only way to get a total reference count.  
What problem are you trying to solve?  Not all objects have names and as far as I know there’s not a complete list of all objects in the system exposed to the user